# contentplaceholder is not accepting main tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having **masterpage** in which `contentplaceholder` is inside a form tag and main tag inside a `contentplaceholder`.

I am using **Bootstrap 4** class.

My problem is `contentplaceholder` content is not displaying showing nothing in browser.

My Code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            <main class="col-md-9 col-xs-11 p-l-2 p-t-2" runat="server">
                <hr>
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h1>Bootstrap 4 Sidebar Menu</h1>
                </div>
                <p class="lead">A responsive, multi-level vertical accordion.</p>
            </main>
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</form>
```

My Output:
[Output Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80k16.png)`<br />`
[Inspect element from Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITZTY.png)

Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong.

Comment: Why have you added the content of the placeholder in the MasterPage? You should add it in the View Page. If you add the content in the MasterPage then you don't need contentplaceholder or you are using it in the wrong way.

Comment: This code is in master page not in the content page

Comment: Then you should remove `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` because it's content is being loaded from Content Page and the content you have added to it in the Master Page is being ignored

Comment: If we remove <asp:ContentPlaceHolder></asp:ContentPlaceHolder> then how the content pages will work

Comment: `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` is designed for being placeholder. You should not add any content to it in the Master Page. All the content of placeholder should be added from Content Page. For which should be specified it's master page. The Contents are being bound by placeholder's ID

Comment: If i removed the contentplaceholder in the form tag and placed below the main tag inside form tag.... It's working but I required the content pages at that point. What should I do now

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx

Comment: I will check and come back a moment....

Comment: Thanks I got the result..... The content should not be placed in the master page as @Samvel said.... The content is pasted in the content pages and checked the output now it's working fine. Thanks a lot